# Override Event Handler in GraphExtension Acumatica 21r1

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to override an event handler, RowSelecting, defined in a GraphExtension (for which I do not have the source or ownership)?
To cut a long story short, I need to prevent that EventHandler from executing (it is the cause of "DataReader already open" errors).
Extending the GraphExtension with PXGraphExtension<BadExtension,Graph> and overriding the RowSelecting event doesn't seem to work. Is it even possible?
Or is there a way to override/deactivate a GraphExtension (without unpublishing the package).

Answer (score 0):

if *public class MyGraph_Extension : PXGraphExtension* is the original graph extension declaration to override it and its methods

*public class MyGraph_Extension_Extension : PXGraphExtension<MyGraph_Extension>*

the override the rowselecting event by

if old method
*protected virtual void MyDac_RowSelecting()*
if new method
*protected virtual void _(Events.RowSelecting e, PXRowSelecting base)*

then either ignore the base method or call it before, in the middle or after your code with

*base(e.Cache, e.Args);*

More help @

[a link]https://help-2021r2.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c86fdae8-fef9-4490-aa57-3528d0fa172e
for over riding extensions

[a link]https://help-2021r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=3914d39a-0394-c506-92b5-3bbe3b044cbb for RowSelecting

Comment: The method signature was wrong. I had PXRowSelectingEventArgs, instead of PXRowSelecting. (Generic event declaration. Neither Compiler nor Acuminator picked it up). Thanks also for the links, Acumatica Documentation is awesome.

Comment: It seems that when you override the event handler and don't call the delegate, it prevents the Base Graph RowSelecting eventhandler from working properly?

Comment: It will either run it when you call it with the Base line added in your method or it will never run if you don't call it